# Tool fixture and holding

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering

How do I hold a end milling tool in a rod which is smaller than the tool(smaller efers to the diameter of the rod).

Comment: Any number of ways depending on constraints ... including the "end milling tool" material. If it's soft (with a carbide insert) drill and ream it, and braze the rod into the hole. If it's hard, grind a length of its shank down to the rod diameter, and use that instead of the rod. Or moount a collet holder on the rod and hold the endmill in a collet. etc etc etc.

Comment: Yeah the collet would work for me think so,thanku